# insert a column value based on index range

Tags: python, pandas

I have a a Dataframe loaded from a .csv that looks like this

```
name          code
accounting
a             1
c             3
HR
b             2
```

I need to change so it reads like this

```
name  code  dept
a     1     accounting
c     3     accounting
b     2     HR
```

What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: Is this in a file? A dataframe?

Comment: Its a dataframe, ive updated the question to make that clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC,

we can use `.loc` to assign to a new column, `ffill` and `.dropna()` to get your target df.

```
df.loc[df['code'].isnull(),'dept'] = df['name']

df['dept'] = df['dept'].ffill()

df_new = df.dropna(subset=['code'])

print(df_new)

  name  code        dept
1    a   1.0  accounting
2    c   3.0  accounting
4    b   2.0          HR
```